# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Thread 1 . code below. swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode8

I`m working on this issue from one week, tried to replace most of the code with new and its still crashing with error below. Googled for one week and researched almost all topics .Finally came here for help.

> 0x10006dc50 <+84>:  bl     0x100072fcc               ; symbol stub
>   for: objc_msgSend
>       0x10006dc54 <+88>:  ldr    x0, [sp, #8]
>       0x10006dc58 <+92>:  bl     0x100072fe4               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
>       0x10006dc5c <+96>:  adrp   x8, 11

EXC_BAD_ACCESS Thread 1 .
code below.

```
//--------------calmingseaplayer----------------- 
do { 
  let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "calming", ofType: "wav")
  try morningdewplayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!)) 
} 
catch { //Error }
```

Comment: Post the code where it crashes. Bad access means an object was released and you tried to use it (or send a message to it)

Comment: import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class music : UIViewController{
    var morningdewplayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var birdplayer       = AVAudioPlayer()
    var calming          = AVAudioPlayer()
    var flute            = AVAudioPlayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
        
        do {
            let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "morning", ofType: "mp3")
            
            try morningdewplayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
        }
        catch
        {
            //Error
        }

Comment: Edit your original post with your code, not in the comments :)

Comment: Doesn't allow me to post entire code ,not sure why ?

Comment: No edit option for the original post

Comment: Just post the part where Xcode stops the execution, if more is required to debug this you can post more.

Comment: //--------------calmingseaplayer-----------------
        
        
        do {
            let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "calming", ofType: "wav")
            
            try morningdewplayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
        }
        catch
        {
            //Error
        }

Comment: I have 6 Mp3 files playing tunes upon touching them . first one works fine, crashes on second one (calming sea )

Answer (score 0):

Force unwrapping is probably not what you want to do here, verify that the url with `audioPath` is not nil by guarding it.

```
guard let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "calming", ofType: "wav") else { print("Incorrect audio path"); return }
guard let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath) else { print("URL is nil"); return }
try morningdewplayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
```

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'URL'

Comment: Oh right, you don't need the second guard, just the first one.